# Python 3 typing - list of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

How do I hint the return type of a function that returns a list of classes in Python 3?

Example:

```py
class BaseClass:
  pass

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
  pass

class SubClass2(BaseClass):
  pass

# Help needed:
def get_sub_classes() -> list[???]:
  return BaseClass.__subclasses__()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
class BaseClass:
  pass

def get_sub_classes() -> list[type[BaseClass]]:
  return BaseClass.__subclasses__()
```

Comment: `List` and `Type` are getting deprecated. Start using `list` and `type`.